# Method for prefixing JavaScript API Interfaces?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

On the MDN docs for [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility), the compatibility table lists basic support for Chrome 18 and Safari 6 with a `-webkit` prefix.

Is this something that is internal to browsers...or is there an actual way to prefix something like `MutationObserver()`?

My assumption is that it's not as simple as:

```
var observer = new -webkit-MutationObserver();
```

...but maybe it is?

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers I think it's internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit-` is used for CSS since CSS properties can have `-` characters in them. In JS, things are prefixed as with `Webkit` for constructors or `webkit` for properties usually.

```
var observer = new WebkitMutationObserver();
```

Generally this is handled with something like

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver ||
        window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver();
```